# SVM predict (e1071) - classifies all predictions as 0

Tags: r, svm, predict

I have this data:

```
> head(k2)
  fromTo adja sims
1  1 - 1    0    0
2  2 - 1    1    3
3  3 - 1    0    2
4  4 - 1    0    5
5  5 - 1    0    3
6  6 - 1    1    3
```

where adja is the class that needs to be predicted (0 or 1) and sims is the main factor that the prediction is based on.

I am using the e1071 library in R, to run the svm on this data. I have the following script:

```
s<- subset(k2, select=-adja)
t <- subset(k2, select=adja)

svm_model <- svm(adja ~ ., data=k2, type='C-classification')
summary(svm_model)
pred <- predict(svm_model,s)
table(pred,t$adja)
svm_tune <- tune.svm(adja ~ sims, data=k2,  cost=10^(-1:2), gamma=(0.1:2.5))

svm_modeltuned=svm(adja ~ sims, data=k2, type='C-classification', kernel = "radial", cost = 100, gamma=1)

p <- predict(svm_modeltuned,s)

table(p,t$adja)
```

If I print p, all the predictions are 0:

```
> table(p)
p
   0    1 
9740    0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are adja and fromTo factors?

Comment: only sims is the factor, adja is the result that should be predicted (binary classification 0 or 1)

Comment: I think the target variable for SVM  classification must be factorized. Have you tried that?

Comment: what do you mean, isn't that handled by the formula in the svm function - adja ~ sims?

Comment: Can you post the output of `summary(k2)`? Can you post your data (using `dput`)?

Comment: `summary(k2)
    fromTo               adja              sims      
 Length:9152        Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.000  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:3.000  
 Mode  :character   Median :0.00000   Median :4.000  
                    Mean   :0.02032   Mean   :4.142  
                    3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:5.000  
                    Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :9.000`

Comment: you need to scale variables using `scale()` in R.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more on how the scale() should be used, because the examples I found did not use them